# Java (Android) HTTP Post to PHP Page

Tags: java, php, android

This is for an Android application ,where my mobile developer is trying to post json data to my PHP page .

Below is the function that is being used :

```
public static String postData(String url, String postData) {
  // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
     InputStream is = null;
     StringBuilder sb = null;
     String result = "";

//   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
//   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

     try {
         httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(postData));
         httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
         httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
         // Execute HTTP Post Request
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         is = entity.getContent();

     } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
         //throw new CustomException("Could not establish network connection");
     }
        try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "utf-8"), 8);

                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                String line = "0";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            //throw new CustomException("Error parsing the response");
        }
  return result;

 }
```

Where url is the link to my php webpage . On my php page , i am just trying to print out the posted data by doing :

```
print_r($_POST);
```

But it shows an empty array . I even tried using the REST addon for firefox and doing the same but it simply shows a blank array .

Would be great if someone could point out if i am missing anything .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the json content like below :

```
if(isset($_POST))
    {
     $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
     $jsonObj = json_decode($json);
     echo $jsonObj;
    }
```